# When are 2 quantities multiplied in physics?

Tags: dimensional-analysis

5*3 = 15. We get 15 by adding five 3 times. Multiplication of 5*3 means adding 5 3 times.i,e multiplication is repetitive addition.Multiplication is perfectly defined in mathematics.

$F= m*a$.

If we use the same definition of multiplication, does Force mean adding mass, acceleration times?

Is multiplication in physics and mathematics different?

Comment: @Downvoters. I think this is a perfectly normal question (A good question I'd say!). Please show the courtesy to let the questioner know why you down voted.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32986/discussion-on-question-by-ramki-when-are-2-quantities-multiplied-in-physics).

Comment: I think this question demonstrates a severe lack of awareness of the nature of multiplication. It might be good on [math.SE], but here I consider it a prerequisite that askers either understand, or be willing to learn about (elsewhere), the basic mathematical tools that underlie the topics they are asking about.

Comment: @David Z: your comment lead me to this post:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063797/understanding-the-concept-of-multiplication

Understanding multiplication is scaling of number(instead of repetitive addition) helped me form the complete picture.

Answer (score 2):

In math and physics *bilinear* dependencies pop up left, right and center. *Bilinear* here refers to a quantity that depends on two inputs such that if one of the inputs grows while the other stays fixed, the observable grows proportionally.

A simple example is provided by the area of a rectangle. We are all familiar with the fact that for fixed width this area is proportional to the length of the rectangle, and also that for fixed length the area is proportional to the width. The mathematical relationship that expresses the bilinear dependency of  $area$ on $length$ and *width* is: $$area = constant \times length \times width$$ 
By using compatible units (for instance by measuring length and width in meters and area in square meters) the constant in this expression can be made to reduce to unity: $$area = length \times width$$

The same applies to the bilinear relationship $F=m \times a$. It expresses the experimentally established fact that the force needed to accelerate a given mass $m$ is proportional to the amount of acceleration, and also that the force needed to accelerate an object by a given amount $a$ is proportional to its mass. Again, to avoid a spurious proportionality constant to pop up, compatible units (e.g. SI units) need to be used for the three quantities in this expression.

Comment: *It expresses the experimentally established fact that the force needed...* Force is defined as such ($2nd$ law of motion), its not an experimental fact to be precise. A good answer to the question by the way.

Answer (score 1):

F = ma is actually just a convenient way of writing these three relationships:

- Multiplying mass with constant acceleration multiplies force by the same ratio.
- Multiplying acceleration with constant mass multiplies force by the same ratio.
- Multiplying mass with constant force divides acceleration by the same ratio.

So, start with the fact 1 Kg at 1 m/s^2 is 1 Newton. Using the first relationship we can deduce 3 Kg at 1 m/s^2 is 3 Newtons. From that we can use the second relationship to deduce 3 Kg at 5 m/s^2 is 15 Newtons.